Understanding Different Behaviors in Unity Rotation Calculation
I have recently begun learning Unity and encountered a perplexing issue. I implemented two different scripts to control the rotation of a GameObject, specifically a ball. In the first script, I calculated the rotation by multiplying by Time.deltaTime in a separate line. This caused the ball to move from left to right and vice versa. In the second script, I calculated the rotation by multiplying by Time.deltaTime within a single line, which resulted in the ball moving forwards and backwards.
// First Code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 100;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed;
        rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
        rb.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.back * rotation);
    }
}

// Second Code
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using UnityEngine;

public class BallController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float rotationSpeed = 100;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float rotation = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        rb.AddRelativeTorque(Vector3.back * rotation);
    }
}

Could someone please help me understand the reason behind this difference in behavior? Thank you in advance.

Your scripts work identically, as expected.
If in one case your ball moves left to right and in the other forwards and backwards, check the transforms of your balls (and/or their parents). The second one is rotated 90 degrees.
